# phpinfo not working on Mac OS X, Apache not up?

Tags: macos, php, apache-http-server

Ok I just got myself a new macbook pro and loving it. I'm trying to set it up as a dev environment.

I'm trying to get my basic phpinfo to work. I installed php from the venerable Marc Liyanage (http://www.entropy.ch/software/macosx/php/#install) When i make a dummy php file called test.php with the phpinfo(); code in it, apparently running http://localhost/~username/test.php should show me something. But i get absolutely nothing. Google chrome throws me a big fat "This webpage is not available".

I'm presuming there's something fundamental i'm missing. The web service should start up on it's own according to install. I even went to System Preferences > Sharing > and made sure Web Sharing is checked. It provides me with the link as well and says that your website...available at the the "Sites" folder. I have placed the test.php in the Sites folder as well.

I'm clueless now, anyone kind enough to help troubleshoot a newb's problem?

Cheers
K

Comment: where are you save your test.php code?

Comment: I'm saving it in the "Sites" folder in my user directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it happens, the entropy distribution i had initially used for PHP+Apache isn't supported on Snow Leopard. Apple Snow Leopard now comes by default with latest versions of php and apache. For more info you can check this link http://www.entropy.ch/phpbb2/viewtopic.php?p=14856#14856 to the entropy forums.

Answer (score 0):

If Apache isn't up, start it up:

1. System Preferences
2. Sharing
3. Web Sharing

   - Check the little box.

Try it again and see if you get anything.

Comment: Hey Jack, i already tried that, after enabling the little inbox, it also gave me the exact url i should be clicking to access my website etc. I simply appended my test.php to the end of that url and tried. but couldn't get anything.